# Eclipse with powerpc-linux-gcc possible?

Tags: linux, eclipse, embedded, powerpc

I program a embedded Linux on a separate target. For that I use Eclipse as a editor and the powerpc-linux-gcc.

That's a bit uncomfortable.

Is it possible to use a  powerpc-linux-gcc in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you want to install (via Help -> install new software -> from all available sources -> Mobile and device development) C/C++ cross compiler support and possibly C/C++ GDB hardware debugging.

When you start new project, selecet C or C++ project, then Executable, then "empty project" (or something else) and then make sure, in to selecet "Cross gcc" in right listbox. Press Next button until the page with cross compiler prefix and path shows. There you need to enter prefix (powerpc-linux- in your case) and you can also select your compiler's directory (if you have not added it to path).

When you have project set up this way, selected toolchain is used to build. You can alse set up "GDB hardware debugging" session to debug your application remotely.